# how to remove margin from TinyMce <p> elements

Tags: css, tinymce

Did any of you figured out how to remove margin from all

elements in editor?
i tried to set

```
   p {margin: 0px;}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like what you need: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

When you init the TinyMCE just set content_style for p:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // your HTML selector
  content_style: "p {margin: 0}"
});
```

Comment: yea i did that but because i am using nette framework  and it uses {} brackets for macros it doesn't work.
My solution is i went to tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css and added p{margin:0px}

Comment: Of course, it goes without saying, just be careful to reinsert it if you update TinyMCE version.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Matteo's answer you could use the `content_css` setting in TinyMCE to put that CSS in a separate (external) CSS file so that you never have to worry about a TinyMCE update removing your changes.  This eliminates the need to modify the skin files while getting the same end results.